# How long has the IRS limit of 25k contribution to ESPP been in place

Tags: discussion

The IRS limits contributions to Employee Stock Purchase Programs (ESPPs) to at most $25000 per year. This limit has not changed for at least five years, during which the CPI has increased roughly 25%.

I am curious how long the $25000 limit has been in place, as I would like to figure out how much it would be if the limit had been adjusted for inflation annually since it was originally set.

Comment: Did you mean to post this on the main site? I can try to move it if so, or you can delete and repost.

Comment: Apologies - new user to this site - yes, that is what I meant to do. I will move it. @GS-ApologisetoMonica

Comment: @GS-ApologisetoMonica, I tried to move it, but am restricted from posting too often - would you mind moving it if you can?

Comment: I've moved it now.